# How to update multiple objects but with the same data in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database

Is it possible to update multiple objects (NOT all of them) but with the same variable?

I want to update few more objects but with the same dataset, can I do it using only one query?

```
   db.getCollection('my.data').update({ "_id": ObjectId("52e637fca92cf1ec6a73c1e8") },
    { 
        "$set": {
            "var1": 2,
            "var2": 3,
            "var3": 4
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update all documents matching your query by adding a third parameter to your update call:

```
db.getCollection('my.data').update(
    {
        "field": "that matches documents to update"
    },
    { 
        "$set": {
            "var1": 2,
            "var2": 3,
            "var3": 4
        }
    },
    {
        multi: true
    }
);
```

This assumes of course that your query matches only the documents you want to update.

You can learn more about the update operator [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

Comment: You can also update specific documents by changing your query parameter to be `{_id: {$in: [ObjectId("doc1"), ObjectId("doc2"), ...]}}`, if you know which specific documents you want to update!